# Cypress - check if the file is downloaded

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have a little problem with trying to check if a file is downloaded.

Button click generates a PDF file and starts its download.

I need to check if it works.

Can Cypress do this?

Comment: There was a [similar question already asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627113/verify-the-data-of-the-downloaded-file-pdf-word-excel-using-cypress-commands). This should help you :)

Answer (score 7):

***cypress/plugins/index.js***

```js
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    const downloadDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'downloads');
    
    const findPDF = (PDFfilename) => {
      const PDFFileName = `${downloadDirectory}/${PDFfilename}`;
      const contents = fs.existsSync(PDFFileName);
      return contents;
    };
    
    const hasPDF = (PDFfilename, ms) => {
      const delay = 10;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (ms < 0) {
          return reject(
            new Error(`Could not find PDF ${downloadDirectory}/${PDFfilename}`)
          );
        }
        const found = findPDF(PDFfilename);
        if (found) {
          return resolve(true);
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          hasPDF(PDFfilename, ms - delay).then(resolve, reject);
        }, delay);
      });
    };
    
    module.exports = (on, config) => {
      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser, options) => {
        if (browser.family === 'chromium') {
          options.preferences.default['download'] = {
            default_directory: downloadDirectory,
          };
          return options;
        }
        if (browser.family === 'firefox') {
          options.preferences['browser.download.dir'] = downloadDirectory;
          options.preferences['browser.download.folderList'] = 2;
          options.preferences['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] =
            'text/csv';
          return options;
        }
      });
    
      on('task', {
        isExistPDF(PDFfilename, ms = 4000) {
          console.log(
            `looking for PDF file in ${downloadDirectory}`,
            PDFfilename,
            ms
          );
          return hasPDF(PDFfilename, ms);
        },
      });
    
      return config;
    };
```

***integration/pdfExport.spec.js***

```js
    before('Clear downloads folder', () => {
       cy.exec('rm cypress/downloads/*', { log: true, failOnNonZeroExit: false });
    });
        
    it('Should download my PDF file and verify its present', () => {
        cy.get('ExportPdfButton').click();
        cy.task('isExistPDF', 'MyPDF.pdf').should('equal', true);
    });
```

Comment: When you shared code snippet, please try to add also explanation

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I usually agree, but this snippet is great and having a test is the explanation.

Comment: Nice example to check if the PDF was downloaded; i.e. if the file exists. Cypress has a similar code (using `cy.task`) to show how to ["Read a file that might not exist"](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Read-a-file-that-might-not-exist).  Also consider the function [`cy.readFile(...)` if you're interested in reading](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile). Finally, [here's another SO example that uses `cy.task`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627113/verify-the-data-of-the-downloaded-file-pdf-word-excel-using-cypress-commands), i.e. for assertions re: file content

Comment: Even [this library seems like it uses a similar approach](https://github.com/elaichenkov/cy-verify-downloads)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to have a look to the HTTP response body.
You can get the response with `cy.server().route('GET', 'url').as('download')` (check cypress documentation if you don't know these methods).

and catch the response to verify the body is not empty:

```
cy.wait('@download')
    .then((xhr) => {
        assert.isNotNull(xhr.response.body, 'Body not empty')
    })
```

Or if you have a popup announcing success when the download went successfully, you can as well verify the existence of the popup:

```
cy.get('...').find('.my-pop-up-success').should('be.visible')
```

Best,

**EDIT**

Please note [`cy.server().route()` may be deprecated](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server#Syntax):

> cy.server() and cy.route() are deprecated in Cypress 6.0.0. In a future release, support for cy.server() and cy.route() will be removed. Consider using cy.intercept() instead.

According to the [migration guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Migrating-cy-route-to-cy-intercept), this is the equivalent: `cy.intercept('GET', 'url').as('download')`

Comment: I don't think the `cy.server().route()` approach will work because a file download is not a `GET` request.

Comment: Thanks François, It worked like charm. 
Before triggering download I am calling a GET api for getting CSV usage, So this approach helped to ensure that response is valid.

Comment: Sometimes a download comes from a GET request that responds with a file, but not always. Sometimes the Blob can be generated entirely from the frontend and downloaded (like generating an xlsx file, for example). @abdp's answer is better in general.